# How i set ListView below match_parent Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, screen

mLayout :

[image]

ListView

[image]

i want to set mChartView to match_parent (fit screen)
and then add ListView below mChartView 
but this only show mChartView

i try set fixed size to mChartView and ListView is work !. but i can't set mChartView to fit another screen size.

my mChartView and ListView using ScrollView

(code below it's work but mChart not match_parent because fixed size)

```
           <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_units"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/label_data_baht"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_chart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp" // fixed size
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                        android:id="@+id/mBarChart"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart>

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_ic_saving" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/tv_saving"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="13sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                         android:background="@drawable/bg_ic_expense"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
                            android:text="@string/tv_expense"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="13sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/BillListYearly"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"  // fixed size
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:focusable="false">

                </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

thank you.

(I apologize for not being word-perfect in English)

Answer (score 0):

Add property `android:layout_weight="1"` to **LinearLayout** of your chart view.

Also make it **`match_parent`** for height attribute,

make your **`ListView`** **`match_parent`** for height attribute.

Comment: thank you. but when i set property this  mChartView is GONE 
i try set  android:layout_weight="1"  for ListView it's does't work
mChartView don't show match_parent